# Understanding Back Propagation for ANNs

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vectors, neural-networks

I have been in the process of learning back propagation for NN's from [this website](http://bigtheta.io/2016/02/27/the-math-behind-backpropagation.html), and I have a question about the derivation of a few values. For these questions I am assuming that the math and theory on the website is correct. If this is not the case please let me know.

My first question concerns what form some of the variables are in. As far as I can tell the activation function $f(x)$ is an activation function like $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, which implicitly operates component wise on the inputted vectors. $f'(x)$ works in the same way. $x_n$ and $y_n$ are vectors with as many components as layer $n$ has nodes. $w_n$ is an $i$ by $j$ matrix if layer $n$ has $i$ nodes and layer $n+1$ has $j$ nodes. When being multiplied, $x$ and $y$ are treated as row vectors. My question then concerns the definition of $\delta$. My intuitive understanding of $\delta_n$ is that it is a vector indicating how the values of the nodes in layer $n$ need to change, before the activation function. As a result, each $\delta_n$ should be a vector. This is, as far as I can tell, supported by $\delta_N=f'(x_N)\left(|y_N-t|\right)$ as $f'(x_N)$ is a vector and the rest is a constant. However, I do not understand why $\delta_n=f'(x_n)w_n\delta_{n+1}$ is a vector. Are my above statements correct, and why is this last statement correct?

My second question is similar to my first, but concerns $\frac{\partial c}{\partial w_n} = \delta_{n+1}y_n$. This value should be a matrix, at least as far as I understand. However, it intuitively does not seem like one and looks more like a dot product. This could be a matrix, if the first vector were interpreted as a column vector instead of a row vector. But if this is the case, what is the mathematical justification for this? And if not, then why is the value a matrix?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, feed forward NNs like this typically evaluate an activation function on a linear combination of its inputs. $$x_{n+1,i}=\theta\left(\sum_jw_{n,i,j}\ x_{n, j}\right)$$ Where $\theta$ is the activation function, typically a sigmoid $\theta(x)=\frac 1{1+e^{-x}}$. This allows you to write relations between partial derivatives of successive layers.

Comment: This is true, and the calculation for these linear combinations are made when multiplying $y_n$ by $w_n$ to get $x_{n+1}$. And I understand back propagation without using matrices and vectors as shown here. My question concerns this specific usage of matrices and vectors to implement back propagation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can write everything in index notation to obtain a more explicit explicitly form. Consider a neural net with $N$ layers and $M^n$ perceptrons in each layer.

$x^n_i$ and $y^n_i$ are the input and output of perceptron $i$ in layer $n$.

$w^n_{ji}$ is the wight between perceptron $i$ in layer $n$ and perceptron $j$ in layer $l+1$.

$f$ is the activation function

Fix $y^n_0=1$ as the bias term for each layer

$$y^n_i=f(x^n_i)\tag 1$$

$$x^{n+1}_j=\sum_{i=0}^{M^n}w^n_{ji}y^n_i\tag 2$$

Now let $t_i$ be a training output. We can define a quadratic cost function $c$.

$$c=\sum_{i=1}^{M^N}\frac 12(y^N_i-t_i)^2\tag 3$$

Now we can define the input gradient of the cost function $\delta$.

$$\delta^n_i=\frac{\partial C}{\partial x^n_i}$$

Which we can evaluate for the last layer using chain rule.

$$\delta^N_i=(y^N_i-t_i)f'(x^N_i)\tag 4$$

And, with more chain rule, obtain a recurrence relation for $\delta$.

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x^n_i}=\sum_{j=1}^{M^{n+1}}\frac{\partial c}{\partial x^{n+1}_j}\frac{\partial x^{n+1}_j}{\partial y^n_i}\frac{\partial y^n_i}{\partial x^n_i}$$

$$\implies\delta^n_i=\sum_{j=1}^{M^{n+1}}\delta^{n+1}_jw^n_{ji}f'(x^n_i)\tag 5$$

Similarly, we can compute the derivatives with respect to the weights.

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^n_{ji}}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial x^{n+1}_j}\frac{\partial x^{n+1}_j}{\partial w^n_{ji}}$$

$$\implies\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^n_{ji}}=\delta^{n+1}_jy^n_i\tag 6$$

These are all of the important equations in the article you provided. However, their notation convention is rather unusual. There seems to be an implied convention for row/column vectors, but I'm not sure what it would be (as a disclaimer, there are many competing schemes of notation for matrix/tensor calculus, and I have only been exposed to a few of them). Instead of interpreting the article precisely as written, I'll rewrite the equations above using the Jacobian formulation of matrix calculus. I'll use capital letters to indicate matrices, arrows $(\vec v)$ to indicate column vectors and transposes $(\vec v^T)$ to indicate row vectors. Matrix multiplication works as normally defined ; in particular the inner product $\vec u^T\vec v$ produces a scalar and the outer product $\vec u\vec v^T$ produces a matrix .

Let $\vec x_n$ and $\vec y_n$ be the input and output column vectors and $\vec\delta^T$ be the input gradient, which by convention is a row vector. Let $W_n$ be the matrix of weights between layer $n$ ad $n+1$. Also, let $f$ act componentwise on vectors ($f$ is essentially a nonlinear transform between vector spaces) .

$$f(\vec x_n)=\vec y_n \tag 1$$

$$\vec x_{n+1}=W_n\vec y_n\tag 2$$

$$c=\frac 12(\vec y_N-\vec t)^T(\vec y_n-\vec t)\tag 3$$

For $(4)$, we'll need to define $J_f(\vec x_n)$ as the Jacobian of $f$. It is a diagonal matrix with entries $f'(x^n_i)$ on the diagonal .

$$\vec\delta_N^T=(\vec y_N-\vec t)^TJ_f(\vec x_N)\tag 4$$

$$\vec\delta_n^T=\vec\delta_{n+1}^TW_nJ_f(\vec x_n)\tag 5$$

In the last  equation, we conventionally define the derivative w.r.t. a matrix, with each entry at position $i, j$ containing the partial derivative w.r.t. entry $j, i$ of the matrix. The left hand side is evidently an outer product of two vectors.

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial W_n}=\vec y_n\vec\delta_{n+1}^T\tag 6$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it clarified a lot of things for me. You change the delta vectors from row to column vectors in step 6. Is there a rigorous mathematical justification for this, or is this something that just has to be interpreted out of the rest of the equation?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy I'd like to mention ultimately a neural network is a sequence of functions  $y_{j+1} = f(M_j y_j)$ where $y_j \in \mathbb{R}^{n_j \times 1}$ is the input of the $j$th layer,  $M_j \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{j+1} \times n_j}$, $f$ is a sigmoid acting component-wise on the vector and $M_j y_j$ is a matrix-vector product. So you can write $\displaystyle\frac{\partial y_{j+1}}{\partial y_j} = M_j^T f'(M_j y_j) $ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial y_{j+1}}{\partial M_j} = f'(M_j y_j) y_j^T$

Comment: My mistake; I was using the wrong convention for scalar/matrix derivatives. Even so, in principle we can take the transpose of a row/column vector without issue, as in $(3)$ and $(4)$. In fact, the placement of transposes is part why there are so many different ways to notate matrix calculus. I would suggest looking up the Jacobian formulation (also known as the Numerator Layout Convention).